# Is this a secure way to convert html to text

Tags: javascript, xss

I have a response from some semi-untrusted API, that is supposed to contain html.
Now I want to to convert this to plaintext, basically strip out all the formatting so I can easily search it, then display (part of) it.

I have come up with this:

```js
function convertHtmlToText(html) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    // assumpton: because the div is not part of the document 
    // - no scripts are executed
    // - no layout pass
    div.innerHTML = html; 
    // assumption: whitespace is still normalized
    // assumption: this returns the text a user would see, if the element was inserted into the DOM.
    //             Minus the stuff that would depend on stylesheets anyway.
    return div.innerText; 
}

const html = `
    Some random untrusted string that is supposed to contain html. 
    Presumably some 'rich text'. 
    A few <div> or <p>, a link or two, a bit of <strong> and some such. 
    In any case not a complete html document.
`;

const text = convertHtmlToText(html);

const p = document.createElement("p");
p.textContent = text;
document.body.append(p);
```

I *think* that this is safe/secure, because scripts are not executed as long as the `div` used for conversion is not inserted into the document.

**Question:** Is this safe/secure?

Comment: Yeah. Using the textContent property will prevent all XSS from being executed. Using innerHTML would be a possible vurnerability.

Comment: Yes, this is the preferred way to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think there are such things as "semi trust" in security. It's all or nothing IMHO. You really should leverage frameworks or libraries for this.

Comment: @customcommander You are right, of course.
What I kind of meant, when I wrote _semi-trusted_ is that I don't consider the API to send hostile content in the general case. 
So I would have to sanitize to prevent possible XSS, but the converted text being garbled or empty would be OK.
Worst possible scenario would be a user getting a false positive/negative search result.

Comment: Some comments here may lead future readers to believe your original implementation was secure; it's not as shown in the answer below. Ideally these comments should be edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not safe at all.

```js
function convertHtmlToText(html) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    // assumpton: because the div is not part of the document 
    // - no scripts are executed
    // - no layout pass
    div.innerHTML = html; 
    // assumption: whitespace is still normalized
    // assumption: this returns the text a user would see, if the element was inserted into the DOM.
    //             Minus the stuff that would depend on stylesheets anyway.
    return div.innerText; 
}

const html = `<img onerror="alert('Gotcha!')" src="">Hi`;

const text = convertHtmlToText(html);

const p = document.createElement("p");
p.textContent = text;
document.body.append(p);
```

If you really can go only with the text content then prefer a DOMParser which will not execute any script:

```js
function convertHtmlToText(html) {
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  return doc.body.innerText;
}

const html = `<img onerror="alert('Gotcha!')" src="">Hi`;

const text = convertHtmlToText(html);

const p = document.createElement("p");
p.textContent = text;
document.body.append(p);
```

But beware these methods will also catch the text content of nodes users can't normally see (e.g `<style>` or `<script>`).